# How to make chip background transparent in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-chips

I am using action chip like:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/copyLinkChip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/copy_link"
            app:chipIcon="@drawable/content_copy_background"
            app:chipIconTint="?attr/primaryText"
            android:textColor="?attr/primaryText"
            app:chipStrokeWidth="0.5dp"
            />
```

And I want to make its background fully transparent how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it programmatically through the [setChipBackgroundColorResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip#setChipBackgroundColorResource(int)) API:

```
copyLinkChip.setChipBackgroundColorResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Or through XML

```
app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it via xml?

Comment: What about app:chipBackgroundColor="@null" ?

Comment: @ChaitanyaKarmarkar Please refer to my updated answer

Comment: Can we also set app:chipBackgroundColor="@null" to make its background transparent?

Answer (score 5):

You can use property  `app:chipBackgroundColor` in XML

```
app:chipSurfaceColor="@android:color/transparent"
app:chipBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: If I use app:chipSurfaceColor="@android:color/transparent" then it obscurs ripple effect.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
chip.setChipBackgroundColor(getResources().getColorStateList(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it via xml?

Comment: What about app:chipBackgroundColor="@null" ?